# Controlar animación CSS con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo dos div con animación en css la cual dura unos 5s. Lo que intento es que la animación del primer div se detenga a la mitad por 5 minutos y luego continúe, al finalizar la animación se oculta el primer div y muestra el segundo div, el cual debería mostrar la animación desde el inicio, detenerse a los 2.5s durante 5 minutos y así sucesivamente como en un bucle.
Hasta ahora lo que tengo es esto, funciona correctamente una sola vez, el texto hace la pausa, pero cuando cambia al siguiente la animación corre infinite sin pausa por Xs.
Lo que necesito es que la animación tenga el bucle que inicie, haga la pausa a los X segundos, continue hasta el final, cambie a texto 2 inicie haga la pausa a los X segundos, continue hasta el final, cambio a Texto 1, y así sucesivamente.

```js
const firstChildElement = document.querySelector("#ani-3 > div:first-child div");

firstChildElement.style.animationPlayState = "running";
 
setTimeout(() => {
  firstChildElement.style.animationPlayState = "paused";

}, 2500);

 setInterval(function() {
      firstChildElement.style.animationPlayState = firstChildElement.style.animationPlayState === 'paused' ? 'running' : 'paused';
      
  }, 30000); 


  const boxy = document.getElementById('info1');
  const boxy2= document.getElementById('info2');
  boxy.style.display = 'flex';
  boxy2.style.display = 'none';
  setInterval(function() {
      boxy.style.display = boxy.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
      boxy2.style.display = boxy2.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
  }, 33000);
```

```css
.animacion {
  position: inline-block;
  right: 0;
}

.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes ani-3-left {
  0% {transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);}  
  30% {transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);}  
  60% {transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
}


#ani-3 > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
#ani-3 > div:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
  
}
#ani-3 > div:first-child div {
  animation: 3.2s ease-out alternate both infinite ani-3-left;
   animation-play-state: running;

}


#info1 { display: flex; }
#info2 { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="info1">
<div id="ani-3" class="animacion">
    <div class="mask">
      <div>Texto 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<div id="info2">
<div id="ani-3" class="animacion">
    <div class="mask">
      <div>Texto 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes implementar el metodo [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) en conjunto con una función recursiva, si deseas que el delay sea de 5 minutos solo cambia la variable *retraso* a 5 min en milisegundos:

```js
let keyframes = [ // fotogramas clave
  { left: '200px' },
  { left: '0' }
]

let anim_normal = { duration: 1000, fill: 'forwards', easing: 'ease-out' } // opciones
let anim_reversa = { duration: 1000, fill: 'forwards', easing: 'ease-out', direction: 'reverse' }

const [texto1, texto2] = document.querySelectorAll('.mask div') // seleccionamos divs

const retraso = 3000; // retraso (pongo 3 segundos para que se note el bucle)

function animar(flag) {
  console.log(flag)
  let target = flag ? texto1 : texto2 // switcheamos que div debemos animar entre cada llamada de funcion
  target.animate(keyframes, anim_normal) // animamos la primera mitad
  .onfinish = () => { // al terminar
    setTimeout(() => { // establecemos un delay, al terminar ese delay se ejecuta lo siguiente:
      target.animate(keyframes, anim_reversa) // animamos en sentido contrario
      .onfinish = () => animar(!flag) // al terminar la animacion en sentido contrario, llamamos a animar() con el valor opuesto de 'flag'
    }, retraso)
  }
}

animar(true)
```

```css
.mask {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mask div {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info1">
    <div class="animacion">
      <div class="mask">
        <div>Texto 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="info2">
    <div class="animacion">
      <div class="mask">
        <div>Texto 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Luego puedes cambiar la duración de las animaciones modificando 'duration' en las variables *anim_normal* y *anim_reversa*, en este caso uso la propiedad *left* en lugar de *transform* para mover el texto, me ayudo de una flag para determinar que div debo mover.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, me fue de gran ayuda!